# How to condition the text color of an element in a RecyclerView ?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, text-coloring

i need to condition the color of a string that appears inside a row of my recycler view when it equals a certain string for example in this case "Halloween over the ages", this is my code, which doesn't work, i'm sure that the setColor statement works well, because when i use it with out the if clause, it makes all the title strings red.

```
//THE TEXT
listRowViewHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(listItems.getTitle()));


//IF THE TEXT IS EQUAL TO Halloween over the ages, CHANGE THE COLOR OF THE TITLE TO RED
        if (listRowViewHolder.title.getText().equals("Halloween over the ages")){

            listRowViewHolder.title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are first converting the text to HTML and then you are pulling that value and comparing it.

One change you should consider,

```
if ("Halloween over the ages".equals(listItems.getTitle())) {
    listRowViewHolder.title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: At the time, your answer did not answer the question, but was rather only suggesting he change the order of the comparison. I've removed the downvote since you've now edited the post to say something useful.

Comment: @SnildDolkow Oh really. I can see that your answer is much useful. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the text is never equal, then. Try printing both strings to the log to verify that they're really equal -- don't forget that leading or trailing spaces would make the strings unequal, as would differing case ("hello" does not equal "Hello"). If they still look identical, try printing the `hashCode()` for both.

BTW, don't forget to *reset* the color for all other views -- when using the `convertView` parameter for your list, you may get reused views that may have been set to red color earlier.